# Android asynctask not showing progressdialog

Tags: android, uitableview, android-asynctask

Below is my Table class which creates a tableview from an XML with `AsyncTask`:

```
public class Table extends Activity {

    readXML readxml = new readXML();
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.table);
        ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);

        performBackgroundTask mTask = new performBackgroundTask(
                getBaseContext());
        mTask.execute();
        // readxml.read();

    }


    private void tableView() {



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TableLayout t1;
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

        TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        tr_head.setId(10);
        tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#afeeee"));
        tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView label_id = new TextView(this);
        label_id.setId(20);
        label_id.setText("id");
        label_id.setTextSize(18);
        label_id.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label_id.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr_head.addView(label_id);// add the column to the table row here

        TextView labelName = new TextView(this);
        labelName.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        labelName.setText("                                Name"); // set the
                                                                    // text for
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // header
        labelName.setTextSize(18);
        labelName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
        labelName.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(labelName); // add the column to the table row

        TextView labelUnit = new TextView(this);
        labelUnit.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        labelUnit.setText("Unit"); // set the text for the header
        labelUnit.setTextSize(18);
        labelUnit.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
        labelUnit.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(labelUnit); // add the column to the table row

        TextView labelMinimum = new TextView(this);
        labelMinimum.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        labelMinimum.setText("Minimum"); // set the text for the header
        labelMinimum.setTextSize(18);
        labelMinimum.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
        labelMinimum.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(labelMinimum); // add the column to the table row

        TextView labelMaximum = new TextView(this);
        labelMaximum.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        labelMaximum.setText("Maximum"); // set the text for the header
        labelMaximum.setTextSize(18);
        labelMaximum.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
        labelMaximum.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(labelMaximum); // add the column to the table row

        TextView labelAccuracy = new TextView(this);
        labelAccuracy.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        labelAccuracy.setText("Accuracy"); // set the text for the header
        labelAccuracy.setTextSize(18);
        labelAccuracy.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
        labelAccuracy.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(labelAccuracy); // add the column to the table row

        TextView labelSensorType = new TextView(this);
        labelSensorType.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        labelSensorType.setText("SensorType"); // set the text for the header
        labelSensorType.setTextSize(18);
        labelSensorType.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
        labelSensorType.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(labelSensorType); // add the column to the table row

        TextView labelRegisterAddress = new TextView(this);
        labelRegisterAddress.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        labelRegisterAddress.setText("RegisterAddress"); // set the text for the
                                                            // header
        labelRegisterAddress.setTextSize(18);
        labelRegisterAddress.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
        labelRegisterAddress.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if
                                                        // required)
        tr_head.addView(labelRegisterAddress); // add the column to the table
                                                // row

        TextView labelOffset = new TextView(this);
        labelOffset.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        labelOffset.setText("Offset"); // set the text for the header
        labelOffset.setTextSize(18);
        labelOffset.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
        labelOffset.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(labelOffset); // add the column to the table row

        TextView labelTimeStamp = new TextView(this);
        labelTimeStamp.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        labelTimeStamp.setText("TimeStamp"); // set the text for the header
        labelTimeStamp.setTextSize(18);
        labelTimeStamp.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
        labelTimeStamp.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(labelTimeStamp); // add the column to the table row

        tl.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // fájl megnyitása hogy tudjuk hány id van

        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File(main.fileWithPath);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("DAQChannel");

            readxml.TablaEddig = nList.getLength();

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // fájl vége

        Integer count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < readxml.TablaEddig; i++) {
            readxml.read();
            // Create the table row
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            if (count % 2 != 0)
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            else {
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            tr.setId(100 + count);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelid = new TextView(this);
            labelid.setId(count);
            labelid.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelid.setText(readxml.getID() + " ");
            labelid.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelid);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelname = new TextView(this);
            labelname.setId(count);
            labelname.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelname.setText(readxml.getName() + " ");
            labelname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelname);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelunit = new TextView(this);
            labelunit.setId(count);
            labelunit.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelunit.setText(readxml.getUnit() + " ");
            labelunit.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelunit);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelmin = new TextView(this);
            labelmin.setId(count);
            labelmin.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelmin.setText(readxml.getMinimum() + " ");
            labelmin.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelmin);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelmax = new TextView(this);
            labelmax.setId(count);
            labelmax.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelmax.setText(readxml.getMaximum() + " ");
            labelmax.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelmax);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelacc = new TextView(this);
            labelacc.setId(count);
            labelacc.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelacc.setText(readxml.getAccuracy() + " ");
            labelacc.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelacc);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelst = new TextView(this);
            labelst.setId(count);
            labelst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelst.setText(readxml.getSensorType() + " ");
            labelst.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelst);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelra = new TextView(this);
            labelra.setId(count);
            labelra.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelra.setText(readxml.getRegisterAddress() + " ");
            labelra.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelra);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labeloff = new TextView(this);
            labeloff.setId(count);
            labeloff.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labeloff.setText(readxml.getOffset() + " ");
            labeloff.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labeloff);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labeldate = new TextView(this);
            labeldate.setId(count);
            labeldate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labeldate.setText(readxml.getTimeStamp() + " ");
            labeldate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labeldate);

            // finally add this to the table row
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            count++;
        }

    }

    // ASync Task Begin to perform Billing information
    class performBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private Context context;

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public performBackgroundTask(Context context) {
            performBackgroundTask.this.context = context;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(table.this,
             "Feldolgozás",
             "Folyamatban...");

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // tableView();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            if (dialog != null)
                dialog.dismiss();
            tableView();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hinnyeeeeeee",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
}// oncreate
```

So the problem:
It doesn't show the progress dialog the first time, but when it ends it shows it for a second and then hides it immediately.

I put in the tableview() void which is doing something with the UI in the on post execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you expecting it to do ? You "create" it in the preInit (And I'm not sure that static call to show() is correct), do nothing in the doInBackground() (immediately return null) and then immediately dismiss it on post execute.

EDIT:

What do you want it to do ? The "normal" progress is:

Initialize in onCreate like:

```
        mSpinnerProgress = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        mSpinnerProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        mSpinnerProgress = new ProgressDialog(MyClass.this);
        mSpinnerProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mSpinnerProgress.setMessage("Working");
        mSpinnerProgress.setCancelable(false);
        mSpinnerProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

In AsynchTask have:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // show the progress dialog
        super.onPreExecute();
        mSpinnerProgress.show();
    }
```

In DoInBackground, have one or more calls like

```
@Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String[]... params) {
       while(loop) {
           // loop work
           publishProgress(<something>);
        }
```

In OnProgress, "do something" to update your message, increase progress, whatever:

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        mSpinnerProgress.setMessage("new mesasge");
             // Or update the progress via .setProgress() whatever.
    }
```

When done, dismiss it:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object obj) {
        mSpinnerProgress.dismiss();
}
```

If you do nothing in the background function, then all you'll see is a flash of the progress bar (MAYBE, because it's shown/updated at a slow rate, so it might not even get drawn via show() before you dismiss it)

Comment: but it works if i do  nothing with the UI...
can you tell me something how to correct it?